# Android onActivityResult() not firing

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am aware of the plenty of questions similar to this one, yet none of the solutions mentioned there work for me, and I'm not quite sure why.

I have the following setup:

Launching from `MainActivity.java`:

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.btn_b);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
});
```

Returning values from `Activity2.java`:

```
@Override
public onBackPressed() {
    System.out.println("Here"); // this can be seen in the logcat
    Intent retIntent = new Intent();
    // putExtra some return values
    setResult(RESULT_OK, retIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Receiving data back at `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    System.out.println("Returning"); // this doesn't fire at all

    if (data != null) { // I know there will be no other activities, and I want to act on whatever result I get
        // extract and do something with data
    }
}
```

I really don't understand what is going on here. Can someone please help explain, and how it can be fixed? I'll be happy to provide more information if needed.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You did not tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line in your `MainActivity.java` to

`startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`

and then in the method `onBackPressed()` call the method `setResult` like this

`setResult(RESULT_OK);`

then in the `onActivityResult` method write this condition.

`if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {//place your logic here}`

Please let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Oh god, this is embarrassing... I started the wrong intent (I had it declared elsewhere)! While your answer wasn't the exact solution, it did push me to finding the real problem, so thank you very much for it. I'll accept the answer anyway.

Comment: @404NameNotFound I'm glad that I was able to help you. But please feel free to post your solution either. Thank you.

Comment: It was merely an `if (condition) { /* start 1 */ } else { /* start 2 */ }`, and I made a change to the `else` case, but I was testing against the `if` case. Still, your answer helped me notice the issue, so thank you!